# LogCat in android studio 0.8.0 doesnt show anything

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

So, i cant seem to get my logcat to work. Doesnt show anything in either normal run or debug. I tried every possible log level and filters.

Im thinking the problem might be in my device though, i tried installing the app CatLog and that one doesnt seem to load any logs also.

Im using Huawei honor U8860 updated with their official release for android 4.0.3. Usb debugging is enabled of course.

Comment: Are you able to get the logs if you run `adb logcat` from terminal?

Comment: Please check in Device Tab that device you are running app is selected or not ? If Selected then click again and take view to logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Well , i was a little hasty to ask. Found my answer myself while later. The problem was that huawei devices have logging turned off by default.

So i had to access the inner settings through dialing *#*#2846579#*#* and changing the log settings there.